# Trouble Formatting docker-compose.yaml in VS Code with Docker Extension

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I'm experiencing an issue with formatting my `docker-compose.yaml` file in Visual Studio Code, and I'm looking for some guidance.

I have installed the Docker extension from [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker). When I open a `docker-compose.yaml` file, the language type is automatically recognized as Compose. Despite my efforts, I can't seem to invoke any formatting extensions. Here's my current setting:

```json
"[dockercompose]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-yaml",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

I've also tried:

```json
"[dockercompose]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

However, I keep receiving the message: "No formatter installed for dockercompose files." I can only format the file when I change the language type to YAML. How can I configure VS Code to format `docker-compose.yaml` files without changing the language type? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: weird... have you saved the settings.json file after editing it?

Comment: @starball  Yes, I'm certain that I've saved the settings.json file after editing it.

Comment: @starball   I just did some troubleshooting by disabling extensions one by one, and I discovered that the issue was caused by the YAML extension from Red Hat (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml).